# Javascript - Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

Javascript Code

```
function myFunction {
  var response = "Hi";
  alert(response);
}
```

HTML code

```
<button onclick="myFunction">Click Me</button>
```

Instead of working the console comes up with the error above.
The script was placed after the HTML code in the webpage.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First of all.. you have invalid HTML there. You need to close the `onclick`. Secondly, this is not enough information to help you. Where did you define the function? Was the button created before or after that function?

Comment: Missing closing `"` on the `onclick` function. Missing `()` at the end of the function call. Missing `()` in the function declaration. I'd recommend a basic JavaScript tutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is a bit off...

JavaScript Code

```
function myFunction() {
  var response = "Hi";
  alert(response);
}
```

HTML Code

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You are missing the brace`()` after the function name. So `function myFunction {` should be `function myFunction() {`

**2.** In the HTML, you are missing the closing quotation marks **"** and also need to invoke the method on the `onclick` attribute.

`onclick="myFunction()"`

```js
function myFunction() {
  alert("I've been clicked!!");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
```